# GoLang Int24 to Int32

Tags: go, byte, bit

Hi guys i wrote this function in GoLang to cast a 24 bit int (3 bytes) to a 32 bit int (4 bytes)

```
func int24ToInt32(bytes []byte) uint32 {
    return binary.BigEndian.Uint32(append([]byte{0x00}, bytes...))
}
```

I want to know if this is a bad solution to the problem. Maybe someone can guide me out to a better and efficient solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your solution is very readable, does what you want, and is *fast enough*.

If you want to make it faster you can just do the bit shifting and or'ing yourself,

```
func int24ToInt32(bs []byte) uint32 {
    return uint32(bs[2]) | uint32(bs[1])<<8 | uint32(bs[0])<<16
}
```

This has no allocations, and doesn't do bounds checking like the standard library.  It's also a couple orders of magnitude faster than using binary package, but we are talking nanoseconds so whether it is worth the hit to readability is really the question.

Comment: Thx so much for taking the time to respond, your answer is really helpfull to me.

Ps: sry for my english